# HTML code for formatting the table cell values in headers of table?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I can't figure out, how do I create a table header style similar to the one in the image? Also, how can I make the name and picture area into a block and add those two borders?

Oh, and how come my icons for my list turned out to be chinese characters, I copied the code for the sideways triangle, but it came out as that. And the codes weren't working for the phone/email either so I ended up using a picture of them instead. HTML code is below:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 800px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px;
}

td {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '\9654';
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<table style="float:right; width: 300px;">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 3px"><img src="phone.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="float: left;">: 747-357-2004</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px">54th Street,</br>17th Floor,</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 3px"><img src="phone.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="float: left;">: 327-127-8390</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px">New York,</br>United States.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 3px"><img src="email.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="float: left;">: rachelgarner@gmail.com</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px">NY 10022</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
</br>
<p><img src="rachel_garner.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="float: left;">
  <span style="font-size: 25px"><b>RACHEL GARNER</b></span>
  </br><span style="color: orange">MARKETING MANAGER</span></br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br><span style="color: blue">www.google.com</span></p>

<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Profile</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Personal Statement:</b></td>
    <td>Experienced in administrative duties; scheduled meetings, handled travel arrangements and purchasing. Computer skills include Microsoft Excel, Access, Word, and PowerPoint. Excellent problem solving and communication skills. Accustomed to long work
      hours. Winner: Employee of the Month 1999 for October and December.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Career Objective:</b></td>
    <td>To obtain an executive sales/marketing management position within a growth oriented, progressive company. I want to apply my business development/sales skills to an environment where they will make a significant impact on the bottom line. The idea
      atmosphere would be entrepreneurial and one in which new ideas are welcome and decision making is required.</td>
</table>
</br>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Key Skills</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is a main summary of my skills.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>Negotiating (Intermediate)</li>
        <li>Access (Beginner)</li>
        <li>Accounting (Beginner)</li>
        <li>Sales Auditing (Expert)</li>
        <li>Invoicing (Intermediate)</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Education</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Bachelor's Degree</b> - <i>Marketing</i> <span style="float: right;"><b>2002 - 2006</b></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>The University of Mississippi</b>, MS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bachelor of Business Administration May 2001 Major: Marketing, Minor: International Business Overall GPA: 3.0, Major GPA: 3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Work Experience</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>University Hallmark Oxford, MS <span style="float:right;"><i>Full Time</i></span></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Sales Clerk</b><i> (Invoicing, Administration)</i> <span style="float:right;"><b>Oct 2001 to Present</b></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Full time roll overseeing the operation of the sales and marketing department.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>Successfully perform managerial duties during manager's absence</li>
        <li>Train new employees and conduct company and product orientations</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what is going on here. I guess you forgot to add the image as well? 
I also see that there are multiple issues in 1 ticket. Try to separate these issues in multiple tickets so that we can analyse them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Without the example image of how the headers are required to look it is impossible to answer the first part of the question.

This is however distinct from the second part about icons. You appear to be using the HTML code for the icons in the content of the arrow pseudo element for example this gives you a completely different character. You need to use the Unicode values. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes)

For a right arrow try this:

```
content: '\25b6'
```

Note that browsers render these types of character in their own ways.